# Repeat a cron (EventBridge) job during a time interval

Tags: aws-lambda, cron, aws-event-bridge

I need to trigger a lambda everyday at midnight and repeat every 10 minutes until 5:00am? Is the best way to do this with a cron job on a EventBridge trigger? If so, what is the cron syntax for "every 10 minutes between midnight and 5:00am"?

Answer (score 0):

`*/12 0-5 * * *` seems to be the answer